# How to get the line numbers for GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a specific way to do this? I'm speaking in general purposes. When I try to launch my program in GDB for example, I get this notification:

```
Reading symbols from /home/amsterdam/Code/c++/opengl_03/bin/opengl_03...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

It makes me wonder if I have to find a specific file for this?

**Update**

Note: I have already tried the following command:

`nm --debug-sym <your_executable> | grep debug`

with no success; it refuses to display anything.

Here is my Makefile:

```
BIN = bin/
OBJ = obj/
TARGET = opengl_03
DEPS = main.o  displayinit.o initializer.o algorithms.o matrix3f.o window.o vertex3.o
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -ggdb 
LIBS = -lglut -lGLEW -lGL 
INCLUDEPATH = -L/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

$(TARGET) : $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)$(TARGET) $(DEPS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 

displayinit.o : displayinit.cpp displayinit.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c displayinit.cpp  $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) #&& mv displayinit.o $(OBJ)displayinit.o
initializer.o : initializer.cpp initializer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c initializer.cpp $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 
algorithms.o : algorithms.cpp algorithms.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c algorithms.cpp $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 
matrix3f.o : matrix3f.cpp matrix3f.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c matrix3f.cpp $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 
vertex3.o : vertex3.cpp vertex3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c vertex3.cpp $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 
window.o : window.cpp window.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c window.cpp $(OBJ)
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c main.cpp $(OBJ)
```

Comment: Maybe there are some useful infos for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151779/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include debugging symbols when you compile. For example if you are using gcc add the flag `-ggdb`.

Comment: for some reason, when I include that in my `$(CFLAGS)` variable, it appears not to work. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Already have used that. It doesn't work either. Here, I'll post my makefile in a sec.

Comment: You should just use one of `-g` or `-ggdb` (the latter says to use gdb symbols) also don't use the flags in the linker stage. Other than that I see no problem. What command do you use when you call gdb?

Comment: All I use is `gdb <executable>`.

Comment: Removing `-g` did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile with debug symbols included `gcc -g` option and make sure you don't strip your executable. More details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390881/gdb-doesnt-show-function-names/8396168#8396168).

-------------------------------------------------Edit-------------------------------------------

Your Makefile does not look good, why don't you use 
[boilerplate Makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559216/what-is-your-experience-with-non-recursive-make8). You can find it [here](http://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake), works well for me.