# Function name is not displaying in GDB

Tags: c, gdb, coredump, pa-risc

I have the core dump file. I kept the c binary application(Built with Debug ON option) in the GDB path which caused the core dump along with the core file.

But when I do `GDB`, I am getting the stack information as below:

```
sura@hyde:/abc/def/ghi/appln [css_absmin] gdb application_name core_1206
HP gdb 3.0 for PA-RISC 1.1 or 2.0 (narrow), HP-UX 11.00.
Copyright 1986 - 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Hewlett-Packard Wildebeest 3.0 (based on GDB) is covered by the
GNU General Public License. Type "show copying" to see the conditions to
change it and/or distribute copies. Type "show warranty" for warranty/support.
..

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
Core was generated by 'application_name'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xc0199640 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0xc0199640 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xc0199640 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

The C Binary is compiled in PA-RISC (unix).

How can I get the offending function name?

Comment: Possibly it is failing in a stripped binary. Use `bt` to see complete backtrace.

Comment: look here to [possible help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390881/gdb-doesnt-show-function-names?rq=1)

Comment: Mohit, I tried backtrace(bt) command as well. Still showing same "#0  0xc0199640 in ?? ()"

Comment: What is the last thing that *isn't* '??' in your backtrace? Post the full backtrace results.

Comment: Added the entire trace.

Answer (score 1):

Sundar,

You posted a question about `gdb` but HP-UX gdb is not a `GNU gdb`, but rather `gdb` customized by HP. So it is called `Hewlett-Packard Wildebeest (based on GDB)` - `wdb`. Your problem is that you have **extremely old** version of `wdb`. Right now HP offers gdb 6.5 (http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=29080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD) for HP 9000 systems running HP-UX 11i v1, 11i v2, or 11i v3 and your version is 3.0!

You seem to have HP-UX 11.00, so you can ask on HP-UX forum what is the latest `wdb` for HP 11.00. Ask here: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Languages-and-Scripting/bd-p/itrc-150#. Also after installing the latest wdb for your PA-RISC  try to get backtrace again with it. I hope you will get a correct backtrace with the latest `wdb`.